# How to select data which is not present in table but present in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table A which is having data `like ( '1','2','3','4')` in `column X`.
I have some data in excel `like ('1','2','3','7','8','9')`.
I need to run a query which returns the data which are not present in `Table A` but present in excel file .
In this case the `result` should be `('7','8','9')`.

Kindly help.

Comment: what you have tried so far, BTW this question is for `sql` or `oracle`. They both are different platforms.

Comment: not yet tried since i was a bit confused . my query would either return values which are present in table  and not in Excel  OR present in excel and table both.

Comment: And the DB is Oracle

Comment: then why tagging `sql`?

Comment: You need to either import the Excel table into Oracle or generate the query using the Excel data and run it in Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to insert the data in excel in separate table first (LETS say `tableA` and `EXCEL_DATA`)
then just fire the statement:

```
 select * from EXCEL_TABLE a 
 where not exists(select 1 tableA from b where a.x = b.x)
```

Comment: yes that is my last option. just wanted to check if i can do it without importing the excel

Answer (score 2):

Assume,
excel_table contains id = {1,2,3,7,8,9} and table_a contains id = {1,2,3,4}

```
SELECT id FROM excel_table WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT id FROM table_a );
```

The result of above query will be {7,8,9}

Answer (score 1):

You must load the excel data into a table. Then you can use NOT EXISTS or NOT IN or MINUS to achieve this result.

```
SELECT colx FROM exceltable MINUS SELECT colx FROM dbtable;

SELECT colx FROM exceltable WHERE colx NOT IN( SELECT colx FROM dbtable);
```